# Pandas merging with different names and lengths for two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join two dataframes with different names.

[image: dataframe]
[image: dataframe]

```py
newframe = pd.merge(detailedresults,seeds, how = 'left', left_on = ['Season', 'WTeamID','LTeamID'], right_on = ['Season','TeamID'])
```

I am trying to merge them by doing this.  I am receiving this error

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

How am I able to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: your keys _must_ be the same on both sides of the merge, `WTeamID` is only on the left what are you trying to join it on? you most likely need to `melt` your first dataframe to match the shape of the 2nd, please see [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

What's the issue with changing `left_on=['Season','WTeamID']` or `left_on=['Season','LTeamID']`. Please provide some more information on what "WTeamID" and "LTeamID" represent.

Comment: I think you just unintentionally solved my problem.  The issue is that WTeamId and LTeamId share the value TeamID in the right dataframe, but they are two separate columns in the left dataframe.  I needed two separate values from the same column in the right dataframe for each row in the left dataframe  I just ended up merging the dataframe twice with each separate value.

Comment: Also take a look at the ```pd.melt``` operation.